# Find all the sym links that point to a particular file

Tags: unix, unix-shell

I know that `ls -l` will give you the "number of links" but I'm looking for a command or combination of commands that will give me a list of all the symbolic links that point to a particular file.

Comment: The links you see with ls -l are *hard* links.  Symbolic links are something else entirely.  Just out of curiosity, why do you care about symbolic links?

Answer (score 6):

Something like this might work:

```
find -L / -samefile /path/to/your/file
```

Obviously you'll need to replace `/path/to/your/file` with the file in question.

A brief explanation:

- `-L` = treat symbolic links as if they were the file to which they refer
- `/` = search from the root of the file system
- `-samefile` = find the files that are the same as this one

Comment: Huh.  I consider myself fairly conversant with `find` but I swear I learn about an option I'd never heard of before every couple weeks...

Comment: I didn't know about it myself until I read through the man page in order to answer this question ;)